# Tablesample Variables are not allowed in the TABLESAMPLE or REPEATABLE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_HistoryDataSensor] 
    @EquipmentID int, 
    @tanggalfrom datetime, 
    @tanggalto datetime, 
    @shiftfrom int, 
    @shiftto int, 
    @sensorid int, 
    @percent int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @datefrom datetime,
            @dateto datetime,
            @tPercent int

    SET @tPercent = @percent

    SELECT @datefrom = (SELECT StartTime FROM dbo.ufn_ShiftDateTime(@tanggalfrom, @shiftfrom)),
           @dateto = (SELECT EndTime FROM dbo.ufn_ShiftDateTime(@tanggalto, @shiftto))

    -- SELAIN SENSOR SPEED
    IF @sensorid <> -99
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            ss.dtCreatedAt AS [DateTime],
            ss.flSensorValues AS [Value]
        FROM 
            tabShiftSensor AS ss
        TABLESAMPLE (@tPercent PERCENT) WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE 
            ss.EquipmentID = @EquipmentID
            AND ss.SensorDefID = @sensorid
            AND ss.dtCreatedAt BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
        ORDER BY 
            ss.dtCreatedAt
    END
    ELSE -- SENSOR SPEED
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            ss.dtCreatedAt AS [DateTime],
            ss.flSpeed AS [Value]
        FROM 
            tabShiftSensor AS ss
            TABLESAMPLE (@tPercent PERCENT) WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE 
            ss.EquipmentID = @EquipmentID
            AND ss.dtCreatedAt BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
        ORDER BY 
            ss.dtCreatedAt
    END
END
```

When I execute the stored procedure, I get an error:

> Procedure usp_HistoryDataSensor, Line 28 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Variables are not allowed in the TABLESAMPLE or REPEATABLE clauses.

How to put variable percent into the tablesample, so I can set the percent of table sample?

Thanks

Comment: you would have to use "dynamic sql" to vary the percentage

Comment: Seems like the kind of queries you should be wanting index seeks on. Not forcing scans with `TABLESAMPLE`. Why are you using it here? The sampling will be on pages before the `WHERE` clause is evaluated and you may end up with a significant disparity of the true percentage of matching results

Comment: @MartinSmith because my application not responding when load big data, so i use sample, when load big value , i can reduced it 10 % of value. or when load small data, i use 100%

Comment: Why not look into how your query is performing instead of tablesampling? You can do order by newid() to simulate the random sampling if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Perhaps look at retrieving rows quickly by using OPTION (FAST 100) if your intention is to have the app respond better. If your app has users looking at pages you may want to consider using paging or only returning the TOP 100 rows.

Comment: because the display data is graphic not page, so when graphic have big data , graphic try to render point its heavy and memory leak, and i cant access the library because its only dll. so i use table sample of all, with the input of editable percent, so the graphic show only sample value (10%) if value 1000 point or more. Or real value (100 percent sample) if the data value 100 point or less.

Comment: If the motivation for using `TABLESAMPLE` is to reduce the data set size to use in a graphic then `TABLESAMPLE`  is not the thing to use. You could forget about that and add `AND CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3) % 100 < @tPercent` to your `WHERE` clause as a first go at this. Or just add a `TOP` as Steve suggests if the TOP X results will be representative

Comment: CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM is a nice tip, @MartinSmith, plus it avoids "wasting" GUIDs

Comment: @siggemannen the `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3) % 100 < @tPercent` avoids the need for any sort operation if it is acceptable just to give each row an x% chance of being included but still the `TOP ... ORDER BY NEWID()` or `BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` may be preferred if need to be specific about the number of returned results (and want all candidates shuffled).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL to inject the percent. This will also simplify the `IF...ELSE...`.

Note that the rest of the parameters should be passed through properly, not injected.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_HistoryDataSensor] 
    @EquipmentID int, 
    @tanggalfrom datetime, 
    @tanggalto datetime, 
    @shiftfrom int, 
    @shiftto int, 
    @sensorid int = -99, 
    @percent int
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @datefrom datetime,
        @dateto datetime

SET @datefrom = (SELECT StartTime FROM dbo.ufn_ShiftDateTime(@tanggalfrom, @shiftfrom)),
    @dateto = (SELECT EndTime FROM dbo.ufn_ShiftDateTime(@tanggalto, @shiftto))

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT
  ss.dtCreatedAt AS DateTime,
  ss.' + IIF(@sensorid <> -99, N'flSensorValues', N'flSpeed') + N' AS Value
FROM 
    tabShiftSensor AS ss
    TABLESAMPLE (' + CAST(@percent AS nvarchar(12)) + ' PERCENT)
WHERE 
    ss.EquipmentID = @EquipmentID' + IIF(@sensorid <> -99, N'
    AND ss.SensorDefID = @sensorid', N'') + N'
    AND ss.dtCreatedAt BETWEEN @datefrom AND @dateto
ORDER BY 
    ss.dtCreatedAt;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@datefrom datetime,
    @dateto datetime,
    @sensorid int,
    @EquipmentID int',
  @datefrom = @datefrom,
  @dateto = @dateto,
  @sensorid = @sensorid,
  @EquipmentID = @EquipmentID;
```

Comment: still same value because the value is 'ss.flSensorValues'. in my else code, the value is 'ss.flSpeed'

Comment: Oh missed that, just add another `IIF` or `CASE`